# A Calculus Question, Derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives

[image]

Please help and explain how to do the problem taking calc online and the teacher is not present right now

Comment: What did you try? What have you done so far?

Comment: I have what A(x) is which is....￼A(x) = 100x + 1000
then I know that I need to find out the cost of the original pizza which is [price]=14-x, but i do not know how to calculate the maximum

Comment: You need to check your gradient. It should be negative. Your y-cut is also not correct.

Answer (score 0):

The required function is an inverse linear function, which means that it has a negative gradient. You are given two points on the line, $(14, 1000)$ and $(9, 1 500)$ where $(x, y) = (dollars, pizzas)$. To find an equation for the line, you need to first find the gradient: $$m=\frac{1500-1000}{9-14}$$ Once you have done that, plug $m$ into the equation $y=mx+c$, then substitute in one of the given points to solve for c (the number of pizzas that will be sold if the price is $0.00).

Once you have the equation for the line, solve that simultaneously with the equation for revenue: $f(x)=xy$ so that you have $f(x)$ in terms of $x$. In order to maximize revenue, find where the derivative ($f'(x)$) is equal to 0.